# linux file creation and umask()

Tags: c, linux, file-io, fopen

I have a program which writes to a log file. Ofcourse this log file and folder has to be created, my program has to run as root so it always create the folder with rw------- permission and it can't be read and write as a normal user. I don't want this, all users should be able to have read and write permission.

my search online led me to umask(000); however it only works on the file and NOT on the folder. The folder that gets created has only rw permission for root and none for all others while the file has the umask permission I set.

anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Do you want only use program to fix it? If not, you could use shell.

Comment: Having `600` permission on a directory is aconventional; using `700` or `500` would be more sensible.  With `600` permission, you can read the directory to see what files are in it, but you can't access the files in the directory (unless you're root).  You can't even create files in the directory (except as root) unless you have `x` (search) permission.  Your `mkdir()` call should be specifying `0755` or something similar as the second argument.

Comment: thank you that worked! you should add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `chmod()` from the `<sys/stat.h>` library which *"[...] uses the specified permission bits and ignores the file creation mask."*, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Permissions.html) for more information.

```
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  if(chmod("test", 0777) != 0)
    printf("Error while setting permissions on directory.");

  return 1;
}
```